# Is there a way to remove *playlists* from YouTube's recommendations?

Tags: youtube

YouTube often offers recommendations (e.g., as thumbnails along the page's right edge, or in the playback window at the end of a video) of stuff to watch.

If one hovers over the title of one such recommended (single) video along the page's right edge, three dots (**⋮**) become visible, and if one clicks on them, a context menu appears that includes the option "Not interested".  Presumably clicking this option allows YouTube to fine-tune its recommendations to me in the future.

So far so good.

The problem is that some of YouTube's most infuriating recommendations are not individual videos but entire playlists, and for these there does not seem to be a "Not interested" option one can click (or a menu for that matter).  At least, as far as I can tell.

Is there some other way to tell YouTube not to recommend such playlists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is a 3 year old post, but in case anyone else has stumbled on this page like I just did, apparently a recent YouTube update now allows us to dismiss the auto generated playlists the same way we can dismiss individual videos and channels via a context menu.
Apparently they added that function to playlist recommendations in a recent update.  Now I can finally unclog my main page of random playlists filled with videos I've already watched and get actual new content to look at.  Yay!

Comment: Exactly *how* does one do this?